# CSS animation reset transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a CSS clock, the minute hand has the following animation styling:

```
animation: a36016 3600s normal infinite steps(3600,end);
```

This allows it to move along as the minutes go by.

When I load the page the minutes hand has a rotation set like this:

```
transform:rotate(180deg);
```

Using setInterval I am trying to reSync it. So for example after 10 minutes if I get the rotation for example as 210deg, and then I change it like this:

```
$('#clock .mm').css( {'transform': 'rotate(210deg)'});
```

The problem is that it doesn't actually set the degrees to 210, for some reason it adds to whatever amount of degrees the animation has already moved. So it becomes 210deg plus whatever amount it has already moved.

Can someone tell me how I can adjust the animation styling so this doesnt happen,  if change the rotation usig javascript to whatever it is, it should set it to that regardless of how many degrees it has already moved.

Thanks

*** BELOW IS THE FULL CODE ***

**PHP**

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");

$hour = date("g");
$minutes = date("i");
$seconds = date("s");

   if ($hour>=12){
    $hour=0;
}

$hourinseconds = ($hour*3600)+($minutes*60)+$seconds;
$minutesinseconds = ($minutes*60)+$seconds;

$hour_degree = ($hourinseconds/43200)*360;
$minutes_hand = ($minutesinseconds/3600)*360;
$seconds_hand = ($seconds/60)*360;    

?>
```

**HTML, CSS and jQuery**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    function SyncTime(){
        $.getJSON('ajax.php', function(data) {
            $('#clock .hh').css( {'transform': 'rotate('+data.hour+'deg)'});
            $('#clock .mm').css( {'transform': 'rotate('+data.min+'deg)'});
        });
    }

    setInterval(SyncTime,5000);

});
```

```css
body {
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100wh;
 height: 90vh;
 color: #fff;
 background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #E73C7E, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);
 background-size: 400% 400%;
 -webkit-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
 -moz-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
 animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Gradient {
 0% {
  background-position: 0% 50%
 }
 50% {
  background-position: 100% 50%
 }
 100% {
  background-position: 0% 50%
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes Gradient {
 0% {
  background-position: 0% 50%
 }
 50% {
  background-position: 100% 50%
 }
 100% {
  background-position: 0% 50%
 }
}

@keyframes Gradient {
 0% {
  background-position: 0% 50%
 }
 50% {
  background-position: 100% 50%
 }
 100% {
  background-position: 0% 50%
 }
}

h1,
h6 {
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 font-weight: 300;
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 top: 45%;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
}


/*** Font for numbers ***/

@font-face {
 font-family: 'WallClock';
 src: url('fonts/wallclock.eot');
}

@font-face {
 font-family: 'WallClock';
 src: url('fonts/wallclock.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/wallclock.ttf') format('truetype');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: 'WallClockPS';
 src: url('fonts/wallclock.otf') format('opentype');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}


/*** Clock rules. Pure CSS ***/

#clock {
 transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#a {
 width: 100em;
 height: 100em;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 50em;
 background: #eee;
 box-shadow: inset 0.5em -0.5em 0 #ccc, inset 1.7em -1.7em 0 #555, inset -0.3em -0.4em 0 #999, inset -0.3em 0.2em 0 #ccc, inset -1em -1em 0 #555, 1em 3em 2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#b {
 width: 94em;
 height: 94em;
 top: 3em;
 left: 3em;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 47em;
 background: #fff;
 box-shadow: inset 0.4em 0 0 #fff, inset 0 -0.6em 0 #ddd, inset 1.6em -0.8em 0 #222, inset -1.6em 0.8em 0 #222, inset 2em 2em 0 #222, 0.6em -0.3em 0 #999, -1em 1em 0 #777, -1.3em -2em 0 #fff, 1.3em 2em 0 #222, 1.3em 3em 0 #999;
}

#c {
 width: 89em;
 height: 89em;
 top: 2.5em;
 left: 2.5em;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 44.5em;
 background: #f4f5f6;
 box-shadow: inset 0.5em 1em 0.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), inset 1em 2em 2em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), inset 0 0.5em 3em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), -1.6em 0.8em 0 #444, 1.6em -0.8em 0 #444;
}

#d {
 width: 88em;
 height: 88em;
 top: 0.5em;
 left: 0.5em;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 44em;
}

#e {
 width: 81.8em;
 height: 81.8em;
 padding-top: 40.9em;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 left: 2.9em;
 top: 2.9em;
 position: absolute;
 border: solid 0.4em #777;
 border-radius: 40.9em;
}

#ii {
 padding-left: 43.4em;
 position: absolute;
}

b,
i {
 height: 82em;
 position: absolute;
 border: solid 0 #222;
 border-width: 3em 0;
 display: block;
}

b {
 width: 1.2em;
}

i {
 width: 0.2em;
}

b>i,
i>i {
 transform: rotate(6deg);
 margin-top: -3em;
}

b>b {
 transform: rotate(30deg);
 margin-top: -3em;
}

b>i {
 left: 0.3em;
}

#f,
#g {
 font: 12em/1.0em WallClock, sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 width: 6.8em;
 color: #222;
}

#g>u>u {
 letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

#g>u>u>u {
 letter-spacing: 0;
}

u {
 display: block;
 line-height: 1em;
 text-decoration: none;
}

u>u>u>u {
 margin: 0.5em -0.55em;
 padding: 0 0.05em;
}

u>u>u {
 margin: 0.0em -1.75em;
 padding: 0 0.7em;
}

u>u {
 margin: -0.55em 0;
 text-align: right;
 padding: 0 1.65em;
}

#f {
 margin-top: -3.37em;
}

#g {
 margin-top: -6em;
}

#g u>u {
 text-align: left;
}

#q {
 font: 2.2em/1em Segoe UI, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: -11.5em;
 color: #555;
}

.ss,
.mm,
.hh {
 width: 80em;
 height: 80em;
 top: 4em;
 left: 4em;
 position: absolute;
}

.hh {
 transform: rotate(-55deg);
}

.mm {
 transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.ss {
 animation: tick 1s normal infinite steps(25, end);
}

@keyframes tick {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 12% {
  transform: rotate(6deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(6deg);
 }
}

.s {
 width: 1em;
 height: 48em;
 top: 6em;
 left: 39.5em;
 position: relative;
 background: #a00;
 outline: 1px solid transparent;
 animation: a360_10 60s normal infinite steps(60, end);
}

.sr {
 width: 3em;
 height: 3em;
 background: #a00;
 margin: -9.5em 0 0 38.4em;
 border-radius: 1.5em;
}

@keyframes a360_10 {
 0% {
  transform: translate(0, 10em) rotate(0deg) translate(0, -10em)
 }
 100% {
  transform: translate(0, 10em) rotate(360deg) translate(0, -10em)
 }
}

.m {
 height: 48em;
 left: 38.9em;
 width: 2.2em;
 position: relative;
 background: #222;
 border: 0 0 32em 0;
 animation: a36016 3600s normal infinite steps(3600, end);
 outline: 1px solid transparent;
}

@keyframes a36016 {
 0% {
  transform: translate(0, 16em) rotate(0deg) translate(0, -16em);
 }
 100% {
  transform: translate(0, 16em) rotate(360deg) translate(0, -16em);
 }
}

.mr {
 width: 5em;
 height: 5em;
 background: #222;
 margin: -10.5em 0 0 37.4em;
 border-radius: 2.5em;
}

.h {
 width: 3em;
 height: 34em;
 left: 38.5em;
 position: relative;
 background: #222;
 margin-top: 13em;
 outline: 1px solid transparent;
 animation: a36010 43200s normal infinite steps(43200, end);
}

#sh {
 width: 80em;
 height: 80em;
 top: 2em;
 left: 1em;
 position: absolute;
}

#sh .s,
#sh .m,
#sh .h,
#sh .mr {
 background: #ddd;
 xbox-shadow: 0 0 0.5em #ddd, 0 0 0.25em #ddd;
}

#k {
 width: 88em;
 height: 88em;
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 44em;
 box-shadow: inset 4.5em 9em 0.5em rgba(250, 252, 253, 0.2);
}


/* Vendor CSS prefixes */

#css3prefixed:checked~#clock {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#css3prefixed:checked~#clock b>i,
#css3prefixed:checked~#clock i>i,
#css3fixed:checked~#clock b>i,
#css3fixed:checked~#clock i>i {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
}

#css3prefixed:checked~#clock b>b,
#css3fixed:checked~#clock b>b {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
}

#css3prefixed:checked~#clock .hh,
#css3fixed:checked~#clock .hh {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-55deg);
}

#css3prefixed:checked~#clock .mm,
#css3fixed:checked~#clock .mm {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
}

#css3prefixed:checked~#clock .ss,
#css3fixed:checked~#clock .ss {
 -webkit-animation: tick 1s normal infinite steps(25, end);
}

@-webkit-keyframes tick {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
 12% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(6deg);
 }
}

#css3prefixed:checked~#clock .s,
#css3fixed:checked~#clock .s {
 -webkit-animation: a360_10 60s normal infinite steps(60, end);
}

@-webkit-keyframes a360_10 {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 10em) rotate(0deg) translate(0, -10em)
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 10em) rotate(360deg) translate(0, -10em)
 }
}

#css3prefixed:checked~#clock .m,
#css3fixed:checked~#clock .m {
 -webkit-animation: a36016 3600s normal infinite steps(3600, end);
}

@-webkit-keyframes a36016 {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 16em) rotate(0deg) translate(0, -16em);
 }
 50% {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 16em) rotate(180deg) translate(0, -16em);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 16em) rotate(360deg) translate(0, -16em);
 }
}

#css3prefixed:checked~#clock .h,
#css3fixed:checked~#clock .hh {
 -webkit-animation: a36010 43200s normal infinite steps(43200, end);
}


/* Fixes */

#css3fixed:checked~#clock {
 transition: none;
 -webkit-transition: none;
 -moz-transition: none;
 -o-transition: none;
}

.fixed {
 display: none;
}


/* Following will fix problems with cascaded transformations
     are critical in Safari, Mobile Safari, Opera,
     non-critical in Chrome and Firefox */

</style><!--[if !IE]>--><style>#css3fixed:checked~#clock .fixed {
 display: block;
}

#css3fixed:checked~#clock .pure {
 display: none;
}

</style><!-- <![endif]--><style>#css3fixed:checked~#clock b:nth-child(2) {
 transform: rotate(30deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
}

#css3fixed:checked~#clock b:nth-child(3) {
 transform: rotate(60deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg);
}

#css3fixed:checked~#clock b:nth-child(4) {
 transform: rotate(90deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#css3fixed:checked~#clock b:nth-child(5) {
 transform: rotate(120deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
}

#css3fixed:checked~#clock b:nth-child(6) {
 transform: rotate(150deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg);
}

#css3fixed:checked~#clock i:nth-child(2) {
 transform: rotate(12deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(12deg);
}

#css3fixed:checked~#clock i:nth-child(3) {
 transform: rotate(18deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(18deg);
}

#css3fixed:checked~#clock i:nth-child(4) {
 transform: rotate(24deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(24deg);
}


/* IE10 fix */

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active),
(-ms-high-contrast: none) {
 #css3fixed:checked~#clock i,
 #css3fixed:checked~#clock b {
  border-left: solid 0px #fff;
  border-right: solid 0px #fff;
 }
}


/* Opera rotation fix */

#css3fixed:checked~#clock .s {
 animation: a360_10of 60s normal infinite steps(60, end);
}

@keyframes a360_10of {
 0% {
  transform: translate(0, 10em) rotate(0deg) translate(0, -10em);
  -o-transform: translate(0, 3.2em) rotate(0deg) translate(0, -3.2em)
 }
 100% {
  transform: translate(0, 10em) rotate(360deg) translate(0, -10em);
  -o-transform: translate(0, 3.2em) rotate(360deg) translate(0, -3.2em)
 }
}


/* Chrome/Windows antialiasing bug. */

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
 #css3fixed:checked~#clock #f,
 #css3fixed:checked~#clock #g {
  font: 12em/1em WallClockPS, sans-serif;
 }
 #css3fixed:checked~#clock #g {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -0.05em);
 }
}


/* Clock size selection */

#clock {
 font-size: 5px;
}

#size25percent:checked~#clock {
 font-size: 25%
}

#size250px:checked~#clock {
 font-size: 2.5px
}

#size500px:checked~#clock {
 font-size: 5px
}

#size10em:checked~#clock {
 font-size: 0.1em
}

#size25percent:checked~#clock {
 font-size: 25%
}


/* Controls */

input {
 width: 1em;
 position: relative;
 valign: top;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
 left: 0.2em;
}

input+label {
 padding: 0.2em 0.4em 0.3em 1.4em;
 margin-left: -1.4em;
 border-radius: 0.3em;
 transition: background 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: background 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: background 0.5s;
 -o-transition: background 0.5s;
}

input:checked+label {
 background: #ABD8F2;
}

input,
label {
 line-height: 1.8em;
}

label {
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}

#clock {
 position: absolute;
 right: 55%;
 top: 50px;
 display: block;
}

#clock {
 margin-top: 4em;
}

body #clock .hh {
 transform: rotate(<?php echo $hour_degree;
 ?>deg);
}

#clock .mm {
 transform: rotate(<?php echo $minutes_hand;
 ?>deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(<?php echo $minutes_hand;
 ?>deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(<?php echo $minutes_hand;
 ?>deg);
}

#clock .ss {
 animation: tick 1s normal infinite steps(25, end);
 -webkit-animation: tick 1s normal infinite steps(25, end);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:700px;;position:absolute;left:748px;top:84px;">Content</div>
<div id="clock" style="margin-top:84px;">
<div id="a">
   <div id="b">
      <div id="c">
         <div id="d">
            <div id="sh">
               <div class="hh">
                  <div class="h"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="mm">
                  <div class="m"></div>
                  <div class="mr"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="ss">
                  <div class="s"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div id="ii">
               <div class="pure">
                  <b><i><i><i><i></i></i></i></i>
                  <b><i><i><i><i></i></i></i></i>
                  <b><i><i><i><i></i></i></i></i>
                  <b><i><i><i><i></i></i></i></i>
                  <b><i><i><i><i></i></i></i></i>
                  <b><i><i><i><i></i></i></i></i></b>
                  </b>
                  </b>
                  </b>
                  </b>
                  </b>
               </div>
               <!-- this is need only to show 
                  bugs-free variant in many browsers -->
               <div class="fixed">
                  <b><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></b>
                  <b><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></b>
                  <b><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></b>
                  <b><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></b>
                  <b><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></b>
                  <b><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i></b>
               </div>
               <!-- till here -->
            </div>
            <div id="e">
               <div id="f">
                  <u>12<u>1<u>2<u>3</u>4</u>5</u></u>
               </div>
               <div id="g">
                  <u><u>11<u>10<u>9</u>8</u>7</u>6</u>
               </div>
               <div id="q">&nbsp;&nbsp;quartz</div>
            </div>
            <div class="hh">
               <div class="h"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="mm">
               <div class="m"></div>
               <div class="mr"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="ss">
               <div class="s"></div>
               <div class="sr"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="k"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="css3icon"/>
```

Comment: provide full code so we can recreate and configure the problem

Comment: @AlaaMh i've edited it to show the full code

Answer (score 0):

This removes the value of the CSS property entirely, will that help?

```
// Reset transform
$('#clock .mm').css({'transform': ''});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work.  I did try this but the animation seems to be overpowering this and the transform does not reset

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not related to changing transform by jQuery or initial value of transform by CSS.

if you have following example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <style>
        .a{width: 100px; height:100px; margin: 100px auto; background: #000}
        .b{height: 100px; width: 100px;transform:rotate(10deg); background: red;}
        
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="a">
          <div class="b">
              
          </div>
      </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script language="javascript">
        $('.b').css( {'transform': 'rotate(20deg)'});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You see that it change just 10 degree and even you change $('.b').css( {'transform': 'rotate(10deg)'}); it does not change.

the problem is related to something else or even a logical error.

According to codes that you sent if you change your jQuery to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function SyncTime(){
    $('#clock .hh').css( {'transform': 'rotate(50deg)'});
    $('#clock .mm').css( {'transform': 'rotate(50deg)'});
}

setInterval(SyncTime,5000);

});
```

After 5 seconds it will redirect to a location and never change its position. the calculation time that pass from ajax.php has issue